# Applicable vs To apply

Tags: word-choice

1) The discount rates applicable to items may vary.

2) The discount rates to apply to items may vary.

Those 2 sentences are both grammatically correct? Or, Which is more preferable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatical, but there is a difference in meaning.

Sentence 1 ("The discount rates applicable to items may vary.") is a general statement likely issued from the company or store to the customer or an employee. It just means that there exist a variety of discount rates.

Sentence 2 ("The discount rates to apply to items may vary.") is an instruction to the employee(s), or whoever will apply the rates. "To apply" indicates that *someone* specific is going to look at the original price and apply a discount rate, which may vary depending on the item. The sentence is not directed at a customer, since customers are rarely allowed to apply discounts to items.

So it all depends on the context. If the correct context is sentence 1, however, I agree with @user184766 that "The discount rates that apply to items may vary" is the most common way to phrase it.

Answer (score 3):

As an English speaker I would naturally be inclined to say

> The discount rates *applicable* to items may vary

Or more often,

> The discount rates *that apply* to items may vary

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would be inclined to say "The *discounts applied* to items may vary." - the discounts having been applied by the company.